# Parse.com Query unable to retrieve multiple objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to query all the parse.com users registered in my app. I followed the guide and wrote this query

```
try{
    name=Name.getText().toString();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereMatches("username", name);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (!objects.isEmpty()) {
                    show.setText(String.valueOf(objects.size()));
                    for (ParseUser singleobject : objects) {
                    mail[i] = singleobject.get("email").toString();
                    uname[i] = singleobject.get("username").toString();
                    i++;
                    }
                } else {
                    show.setText("No Tuples");
                }
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Query Not Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
  }catch (NullPointerException x){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null Pointer Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }}
```

This query works well when the input retrieves a single tuple but when I give an input that retrieves multiple tuples it is throwing a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION like this

```
Process: com.example.nirmal.sportsparse, PID: 15097
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.nirmal.sportsparse.search_players$2.done(search_players.java:108)
        at com.example.nirmal.sportsparse.search_players$2.done(search_players.java:99)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error code says that there is a NULL pointer in `findInBackground()` and
inside the `for` loop. I am sure that the input I gave must retrieve atleast 2 tuples as a result.

Sometimes it also throws this error and I have no idea what this means

```
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
        at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:220)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:700)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The array are declared like this

`String name,mail[]=new String[100],uname[]=new String[100];`

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong??

Comment: what about  'i' value where u declared ?

Comment: @RameshBhupathi The i is initialised before the try block. Looks like I didn't copy it while pasting the code. But it is there and initialised to 0.

Comment: check declaration of arrays ,its better to use Arraylists instead arrays

Comment: @RameshBhupathi I have posted the array declaration.Please check if there is anything wrong with it. I will try to implement Arraylists

Comment: if u have any problem with Arraylist usage just ask

Comment: get("email"    or get("username"  may return null. thus your exception . check the parse dashboard and the corresponding cols. for 'undefined' values

Comment: `User` class is protected, so you need to use cloud function to retrieve the list. In your cloud code, use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` to retrieve with master key.

Comment: @RobertRowntree is right I had 2 tuples that didn't have any data in mail column.After I gave somedata it worked.Please post the answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback "done" , the JSON API , Normally allow 2 steps...

Check element exists

Stringify element

Note that

```
uname[i] = singleobject.get("username").toString();
```

Trys doing it all at once and throws an exception on columns that may be "undefined" in the parse object returned.

Check exists first

Then stringify